# Symfony serializer configure yaml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6, symfony-components

I have my custom service, e.g.. `MyService` with serializer

```php
<?php
    
declare(strict_types=1);
    
namespace App\Common;
    
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
    
class MyService
{
    public function __construct(private readonly SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
    }
}
```

I need to use serializer like this:

```php
new Serializer(
    normalizers: [
        new ObjectNormalizer(propertyTypeExtractor: new ReflectionExtractor()),
    ],
    encoders: [new JsonEncoder()]
);
```

How should i configure that via `services.yaml` ?

```yaml
    App\Common\MyService:
        arguments:
            $serializer: '@serializer' #????
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed: i created new serializer component

```php
final class MySerializer extends \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $normalizers = [
            new ObjectNormalizer(propertyTypeExtractor: new ReflectionExtractor()),
        ];
        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
        parent::__construct($normalizers, $encoders);
    }
}
```

and inject into my service...

```php
class MyService
{
    public function __construct(private readonly MySerializer $serializer)
    {
    }
}
```

without configs... looks like symfony style...